# How to make this 3-D Plot Transparent?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Basically, I want to make this 3-D Plot transparent. I've already tried `Opacity[]`. I also want to change its color to e.g. light blue.

```
α= 1;
β= 1;
tmp = 0.1316;
ρ= 0.01;
t = -1.5;

fe[m_, p_] := 
 1/2*(t - 1)*p^2 + 1/4*p^4 + (1/2*\α^2*β*m^2*(t - tmp)) + 
  1/4 α^2*(β)*(m^4) + 1/2*(\ρ*(p^2)*(m^2))

Show[SliceContourPlot3D[-z, 
  z == fe[m, p], {m, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {z, -6, 6}]]
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, why use `SliceContourPlot3D` when `Plot3D` will do?

Comment: it will return to some error @Rahul

Comment: What error do you get with `Plot3D[fe[m, p], {m, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}]`?

Comment: It works, but somehow it shown different 3-D Graph. @Rahul

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `ContourShading` with `Directives` to achieve both.

```
 α = 1; β = 1; tmp = 0.1316; ρ = 0.01; t = -1.5; 

    fe[m_, p_] := 1/2*(t - 1)*p^2 + 1/4*p^4 + (1/2*α^2*β*m^2*(t - tmp)) + 
      1/4 α^2*(β)*(m^4) + 1/2*(ρ*(p^2)*(m^2)) ; 

 SliceContourPlot3D[-z, z == fe[m, p], {m, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {z, -6, 6}, 
          ContourShading -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.5]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: can we remove the contour line? @RunnyKine

Comment: @Nabil Yes. Add `Contours -> None`

Answer (score 9):

You can add transparency to a color function. No need to make the whole plot to have one color.

```
Show[SliceContourPlot3D[-z, 
  z == fe[m, p], {m, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {z, -6, 6}, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{z}, Opacity[0.4, #] &@ColorData["TemperatureMap"][z]], 
  ContourStyle -> None]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I like your `ColorFunction` approach.

Comment: @RunnyKine I can't figure out how to obtain the default `ColorFunction` so you can apply `Opacity` to it.  Any ideas?

Comment: The following should give you the `ColorFunction`: `ff = Trace[
    SliceContourPlot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)], 
     x^3 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 
      2}], _Blend &] // Flatten // ReleaseHold`. Then: `cf = Function[{x}, Blend[x, #] &]@ff`

Comment: @RunnyKine it works for this case! I asked a question about general solution.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps not entirely what you'd want but for fun sake:

**Example:**

```
SliceContourPlot3D[-z, z == fe[m, p], {m, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {z, -6, 6},ContourShading -> None];
```

**Output:**

[image: output example]

**Reference:**

[ContourShading](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourShading.html)

Comment: can perhaps the contour line, we change it into fish net line? @E.Doroskevic

Comment: `ContourStyle[]` does not really work

Comment: @Nabil I am afraid I am not sure how to achieve this, but I am sure someone else could implement this. There are some brilliant people here, you came to the right place :)