# Extracting unknown ColorFunction from Plot, Plot3D etc

Tags: plotting, color, options

I wonder if there is a way  to extract existing `ColorFunction` and "override" it with a new function that will depend on original one.
[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112926/how-to-make-this-3-d-plot-transparent) discusses different ways how to add transparency to 3D plot, including an "extraction procedure" proposed by @RunnyKine:

```
Trace[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], _Blend & ] // 
  Flatten // ReleaseHold
Trace[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], _Blend &] // Flatten // ReleaseHold
Trace[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    ColorFunction -> (#^2 &)], _Blend &] // Flatten // ReleaseHold
```

It works if you know in advance that the `ColorFunction` uses `Blend`, but for general `ColorFunction` (case three in the above code) it doesn't work. These were just examples to illustrate the extraction algorithm. I want a procedure that will work for any plotting object without any assumptions about its `ColorFunction`.

Is there a way to obtain `ColorFunction` from plotting functions?
I wonder if I'm missing some simple solution a la

```
ColorFunction /. Options[Plot] (* Automatic .. not very useful *)
```

Comment: How about: `Trace[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction ->(#^2 &)], HoldPattern@Rule[ColorFunction, _]] // Flatten`

Comment: `ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}]]` ? Your `Trace` gets empty  list...

Comment: @Kuba I agree the question needs some editing.

Comment: @Kuba I edited the question

Comment: @Kuba The `Trace` was proposed as a possible solution for extracting `ColorFunction` from a plot. The examples show that it works sometime, but it fails for other cases. Generally I don't know in advance that the `Blend` was used. I want a procedure that treats a `Plot` as a black box and gives me the `ColorFunction` that will be used when this `Plot` is evaluated.

Comment: I'm sorry but if you can evaluate `Plot` I don't see why you need to "extract" color function and not use `Composition` or whatever.

Comment: @Kuba Assume I have a plot and it is great. I really like the colors and I don't want to completely modify the ColorFunction by passing my own custom one. I want to replace one color maybe. So I extract `ColorFunction` and modify it slightly and then place it back into the Plot.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't allow the extraction and reconstruction of the unknown `ColorFunction`, but it does allow to override it with an exact duplicate that is transparent,

```
plt1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (#^2 &),
    ImageSize -> 300];
plt2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#^2] &), 
   ImageSize -> 300];
plt3 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> (LABColor[#^2, #, 1 - #] &), ImageSize -> 300];
{plt1, plt2, plt3}
{plt1, plt2, plt3} /. a_ /; ColorQ[a] :> Directive[Opacity[.5], a]
```

[image]

### Edit

So extracting a color function from a plot is not simple, and I haven't got a one-size fits all solution.  Basically, you need to extract the colors from the plot, extract the points, order the colors and the points together, and then use `Blend` to create a color interpolating function.

To top it off, the original plot may have used x or y to base their color function on.  Here's an example, where I use a ColorFunction which is just a modified form of one of the built-in.

```
reconstructColorFunction[plt2_] := 
 Module[{order, points, colors, reconstructedcolorfunc1, 
   reconstructedcolorfunc2},
  order = Cases[plt2, Line[{a__}, b__] :> a, Infinity];
  points = 
   Cases[plt2, GraphicsComplex[{a__}, b__] :> a, Infinity][[order]];
  colors = (Cases[plt2, Rule[VertexColors, {a__}] :> a, 
       Infinity] /. {a_?(SameQ[ArrayDepth[#], 2] &) :> (RGBColor /@ 
          a), a_?(SameQ[ArrayDepth[#], 1] &) :> (GrayLevel /@ 
          a)})[[order]];
  reconstructedcolorfunc1 = 
   Blend[Transpose[{points[[All, 1]], colors}], #] &;
  reconstructedcolorfunc2 = 
   Blend[Transpose[{points[[All, 2]], colors}], #] &;
  {BarLegend[{reconstructedcolorfunc1[#] &, 
     MinMax@points[[All, 1]]}],
   BarLegend[{reconstructedcolorfunc2[#] &, 
     MinMax@points[[All, 2]]}]}
  ]
```

Here it is tested on a few built-in color functions

```
{plot1, plot2, plot3, 
  plot4} = {Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (#2^2 &), 
   ImageSize -> 300],
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (#1^2 &), 
   ImageSize -> 300],
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][#2^2] &), 
   ImageSize -> 300],
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][#1^2] &), 
   ImageSize -> 300]}
```

[image]

```
reconstructColorFunction /@ {plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4}
```

[image]

Comment: That's really nice (although I need to work with your code to fully understand it) but I was really into extracting `ColorFunction`.  I edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: @BlacKow - I don't know that you can recover the exact original color function, but you can reconstruct it with a lot of work.  See the edit, it isn't a black box, but it works on what I've tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to extract such information from an already evaluated plot. `Plot` returns a `Graphics` object and very little meta-information is stored. We can see this by inspecting with `InputForm`.

```
InputForm[Plot[1, {x, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotPoints -> 2]]
```

> ```
> Graphics[{GraphicsComplex[{{1.*^-6, 1.}, {0.999999, 1.}, {0.5, 1.}}, 
>  {{{}, {}, {Directive[Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]], Line[{1, 3, 2}, VertexColors -> Automatic]}}}, 
>  VertexColors -> {Hue[0.], Hue[0.], Hue[0.]}], {}}, {DisplayFunction -> Identity, PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05]}}, 
>  PlotRangeClipping -> True, ImagePadding -> All, DisplayFunction -> Identity, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), Axes -> {True, True}, AxesLabel -> {None, None}, 
>  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, DisplayFunction :> Identity, Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, False}}, FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}, 
>  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, GridLines -> {None, None}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]], 
>  Method -> {"DefaultBoundaryStyle" -> Automatic, "DefaultMeshStyle" -> AbsolutePointSize[6], "ScalingFunctions" -> None}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0., 2.}}, 
>  PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}}]
> ```

But we can *somewhat* reverse engineer the `ColorFunction` and approximate it with interpolating functions.

First here's a plot with a custom `ColorFunction`:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[Pi x], {x, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["FruitPunchColors", Max[-#1, #2]] &)]
```

[image]

Now extract the data points and the color information. Note colors are either stored as an array or as explicit colors, so we need to check for both. Also if there was no `ColorFunction` to begin with, this method will fail, though one could modify the code to account for that case.

```
pts = First[Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[l_, ___] :> l, Infinity]];
colors = First[Join[
  Cases[plot, _[VertexColors, l_?ArrayQ] :> l, Infinity],
  Cases[plot, _[VertexColors, l:{__?ColorQ}] :> List @@@ ColorConvert[l, "RGB"], Infinity]
]];
```

Now interpolate.

```
{red, green, blue} = 
  Interpolation[Transpose[{pts, #}], InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ Transpose[colors];
```

Now here's where it gets a bit hand-wavy. Our data is not of full measure, so extrapolation will need to be used. It seems like restricting the domain to the convex hull of our data gives reasonable results though.

```
dom = ConvexHullMesh[pts];
Show[dom, plot]
```

[image]

And now sample values *only* in this domain. They look reasonable to me.

```
Plot3D[
  {red[x, y], green[x, y], blue[x, y]}, 
  {x, y} ∈ dom, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}
]
```

[image]

I'm not sure if I've really addressed your question. So please ask if you'd like me to elaborate on something.

Comment: Nice - I think I came to a very similar solution with my edit, went through almost at the same time.  Yours is easier to read - I thought it was necessary to reorder the points in the order they are plotted before making the interpolation function (if you try `ListLinePlot[pts]` then you see they appear to be in random order), but apparently I was wrong.  Also, it's tricky when `GrayLevel` is used as the original `ColorFunction` because then the `VertexColors` are stored as a 1-dimensional list.

Comment: @JasonB I was not aware `GrayLevel` could be specified with a one dimensional list, thanks! I think all valid specs are listed in the details section [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html).

Comment: @JasonB And about interpolation, I realized they didn't need to be in order because `Interpolation` threw me the message `udeg` (see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Interpolation/udeg.html)). This doc page gives insight on the interpolation method used: It involves taking working the convex hull of the points, and hence any ordering is ignored. I think this is why restricting the domain to the convex hull works well but larger domains don't.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the original method was copied from my answer to [The default ColorFunction of DensityPlot before v10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71891/121)  That was not intended to be a universal reusable function, only an expedient interactive way to get the information desired.

Neither that original case nor as I perceive them the examples in your own question require the recovery of a color function *from an already evaluated `Plot`* as JasonB and Chip Hurst attempted; that is surely a far harder problem!
I think instead you "merely" need to find what the color function either *is defined by* or *will resolve to* for an **unevaluated** `Plot` expression.

It is easy enough to extract an explicitly specified `ColorFunction`, or one specified with [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html), using a replacement rule and [`OptionValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionValue.html).*  However this does not easily find values set through the Plot Theme or resolve `Automatic` into an actual color function.  The Theme case could be handled as done in [How to access new colour schemes in version 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54486/121) or [Match colors to plot themes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66923/121) but one will find that that sometimes resolves to `Automatic`, and it turns out we can handle both using one method so I propose skipping PlotTheme resolution.

For this we can use [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) as we started with but we need to make it more general.  A bit of spelunking indicates that we can intercept Legend information to do this.

```
Attributes[getLegendData] = HoldFirst;

getLegendData[expr_, key_String] :=
  Flatten[
    Trace[expr, System`ProtoPlotDump`legendData @ key, TraceForward -> True]
  ][[2, 1]]
```

Testing:

```
p[1] := Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
p[2] := Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
p[3] := Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (#^2 &)];
p[4] := DensityPlot[x y, {x, y} ∈ Disk[], PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
p[5] := DensityPlot[x y, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]]

getLegendData[p[#], "ColorFunction"] & ~Array~ 5 // Column
```

[image]

- Note that the second argument is a String, `"ColorFunction"`.
- Strings that appear in this `Trace` are known to include

  ```
  {"ArgumentExpression", "ArgumentLength", "AspectRatio", "AutoLegend", "BarOrigin", 
  "BaseStyle", "BoundaryStyle", "ChartBaseStyle", "ChartElements", "ChartLayout", 
  "ChartStyle", "ColorFunction", "ColorFunctionScaling", "Contours", "DataExtremes", 
  "DefaultLabels", "DefaultLegendFunction", "DefaultOptions", "Depth", "Dimensions", 
  "ImageSize", "Joined", "LabelStyle", "LegendAppearance", "PlotMarkers", 
  "PlotStyle", "StyleWrappers", "WrapperLegends"}
  ```

---

* Since `Trace` involves evaluation of the `Plot` we may sometimes want the simpler but less robust method.  Here is a generalized function to complement `setOpts` from [Setting options of expressions similar to using SetOptions on objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38827/121):

```
Attributes[getOpts] = HoldFirst;

getOpts[p : h_[___], option_] :=
  Unevaluated[p] /.
    HoldPattern[h][___, OptionsPattern[]] :>
      OptionValue[option]
```

Now:

```
getOpts[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], ColorFunction]

getOpts[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (#^2 &)], ColorFunction]

getOpts[Grid[{}, Background -> Red], {Alignment, Frame, Background}]
```

> ```
> Automatic
>
> #1^2 &
>
> {{Center, Baseline}, None, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}
> ```