# Is it possible to determine the individual rgb colors in a color scheme?

Tags: color

I really like the color scheme for ArmyColors and was wondering if I could extract the rgb colors for any point in a chart.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"ArmyColors"` is a gradient color scheme.  You can get the color function with:

```
ColorData["ArmyColors"]
```

> ```
> ColorDataFunction["ArmyColors", "Gradients", {0, 1}, Blend["ArmyColors", #]& ]
> ```

You can use this to get colors for any number of divisions, e.g.:

```
 ColorData["ArmyColors"] /@ Subdivide[5]
```

[image]

Or if you want RGB *values* rather than [`RGBColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RGBColor.html) expressions:

```
List @@@ ColorData["ArmyColors"] /@ Subdivide[5]
```

> ```
> {{0.45684, 0.59295, 0.506035},
>  {0.480465, 0.591726, 0.433138},
>  {0.553916, 0.589613, 0.425472},
>  {0.594656, 0.556339, 0.43209},
>  {0.657761, 0.628066, 0.515469},
>  {0.762737, 0.757717, 0.654841}}
> ```

For other cases please also see:

- [Extracting unknown ColorFunction from Plot, Plot3D etc](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112945/121#123155)
- [Match colors to plot themes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66923/121)
- [How to access new colour schemes in version 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54486/121)

Comment: Many thanks.  Worked perfectly!

Comment: @ouadad You are welcome.  If you find this answer fully satisfactory please consider [Accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 1):

So you can do this:

```
P = Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}]], {x, 0, 10},   Filling -> Axis];
Cases[P, _RGBColor, Infinity]
```

> {RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], RGBColor[
>    0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], RGBColor[
>    0.880722, 0.611041, 0.142051], RGBColor[
>    0.880722, 0.611041, 0.142051], RGBColor[
>    0.560181, 0.691569, 0.194885], RGBColor[
>    0.560181, 0.691569, 0.194885], RGBColor[
>    0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179], RGBColor[
>    0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179], RGBColor[
>    0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], RGBColor[
>    0.880722, 0.611041, 0.142051], RGBColor[
>    0.560181, 0.691569, 0.194885], RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179]
>    }